# Assigning list values to corresponding text inputs

Tags: jquery, list, input, each, closest

http://jsfiddle.net/22fUL/10/

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong here?

I'm trying to populate several inputs with the values from a corresponding list.

```
<dl class="list">
<dt><a href="/" id="list_name">Colors</a></dt>
<dd>
    <ol id="list_items">
        <li><a href="/">White</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Blue</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Orange</a></li>
     </ol>
 </dd>
 <dt><a class="agree">Agree</a></dt>
</dl>

<input type="text" id="myList_item_1" /><br />
<input type="text" id="myList_item_2" /><br />
<input type="text" id="myList_item_3" /><br />
<input type="text" id="myList_item_4" /><br />
<input type="text" id="myList_item_5" />


$('.agree').click(function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
var i = 1;

var items = $(this).closest('.list_items').children('li');

$(items).each(function()
{
$('#myList_item_'+i).(this).val();
}
i++;
);
```

Comment: The question as it stands relies on an outside source. Please rectify that by posting your relevant code here.

Comment: Done - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an underscore -

$('#myList_item_'+i).(this).val();

Comment: Good spot. I don't think that's the only bug though.

Answer (score 0):

`#list_items` is an ID, not a class.

```
$('.agree').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var items = $('#list_items').children('li');

    $(items).each(function(i, e) {
        $('#myList_item_'+ (i+1)).val(e.innerText);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/22fUL/14/)